# py2app Modules not found during compile on OSX 10

Tags: python, macos, py2app

Error while compiling a python script into an Mac app using py2app on (OS X 10.10)
the compile runs until the end, but gives error msg.

setup scrip:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Main.py']
OPTIONS = {'iconfile':'LOGO.icns',}

setup(
    app = APP,
    options = {'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires = ['py2app'],
)
```

On the Main Script I'm only importing 3 modules:

```
import os
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
from Tkinter import Tk
```

I run the setup script in the terminal, it creates the 2 folders (build and Dist) full of files but the app file inside Dist doesn't do anything, not even the error msg.

When I'm compiling I get this error right at the end, before "Done":

> Modules not found (unconditional imports):
>   * **main**.**requires** (pdb)
>   * _weakref.CallableProxyType (_weakrefset)
>   *_weakref.ProxyType (_weakrefset)
>   * _weakref.ReferenceType (_weakrefset)
>   * _weakref.getweakrefcount (_weakrefset)
>   *_weakref.getweakrefs (_weakrefset)
>   * _weakref.proxy (_weakrefset)
>   * errno.EINVAL (os)
>   * errno.ENOENT (os)
>   * java.System (java.lang)
>   * nt._getfullpathname (os)
>   * nt._isdir (os)
>   * org (copy, org.python.core)
>   * org.PyStringMap (org.python)
>   * org.python (copy, pickle)
>   * org.python.core (pickle)
>   * org.python.core.PyStringMap (copy)
>   * pwd.getpwnam (getpass)
>   * sys.py3kwarning (os)
>   * thread._local (collections)
>   * thread.allocate_lock (collections)
>   * thread.stack_size (collections)
>   * urllib.parse (pkg_resources)
>
> Modules not found (conditional imports):
>   * _md5 (hashlib)
>   * _sha (hashlib)
>   * importlib._bootstrap (pkg_resources)
>   * java (platform) 
>   * java.lang (platform)
>   * riscospath (os)

If I run the main script directly from the terminal the main script works.

Any ideias??

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be caused by a too long path.

```
My application is in a path 61 chars long:
$ pwd|wc -c
      61
```

and I get this error:

> Modules not found (conditional imports):  * importlib._bootstrap
>   (pkg_resources)

And the build works if I remove a few characters to the path:

```
$ pwd|wc -c
      59
```